# How can you remove the vowels in a function using a list comprehension?

Tags: python

```
def novowelsort(the_list):
  # TODO perform no vowel sort on `the_list`.
  vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
  list2 = the_list
  list2 = [list2[n] = list2[n].replace(vowel, "") for n in range(len(list2)) if n in vowels]
  return list2


if __name__ == '__main__':
  # Example calls to your function.
  print(novowelsort(['alpha', 'beta']))
  print(novowelsort(['once', 'upon', 'abc', 'time', 'there', 'were', 'some', 'words']))
```

I am working on a task which requires me to sort the words in a list without taking into account the vowels (see above). I do not quite know the syntax for this list comprehension and I want to convert every vowel in the list to an empty string `""`. I have already tried using a `.replace()` function but it returns a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: You cannot do any assignment in a list comprehension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your code, specifically this line:

```
list2 = [list2[n] = list2[n].replace(vowel, "") for n in range(len(list2)) if n in vowels]
```

- you can not assign `=` within a list comprehension, just remove the `list2[n] =` part
- `vowel` is not defined, you should probably execute this in a loop `for vowel in vowels`
- the check `if n in vowels` does not make sense; `n` is an `int`, whereas `vowels` is a list of `str`

To keep close to your approach, you can try this:

```
def novowelsort(the_list):
    vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
    list2 = the_list
    for v in vowels:
        list2 = [list2[n].replace(v, "") for n in range(len(list2))]
    return list2
```

Or using a regular expression to replace all vowels at once:

```
import re
def novowelsort(the_list):
    return [re.sub(r"[aeiou]", "", x) for x in the_list]
```

However, note that none of those actually *sorts* anything, as the name of the function implies.

Answer (score 0):

```
def novowelsort(the_list):
     vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
     return [''.join([c for c in word if c not in vowels]) for word in the_list]
```

Comment: That's also a nice approach, but better make `vowels` a `set` then, otherwise you have one O(n) list lookup for each character. (Technically it's still O(1) as the list has a fixed small size, but anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

For once

```
[list2[n] = list2[n].replace(vowel, "") for n in range(len(list2)) if n in vowels]
```

will create a new list. So there is no need the change up the original list2. Also Python does not allow assignments while creating a list this way resulting in the SyntaxError.

Another mistake is that vowel was never assigned. You probably mend `list2[n].replace(vowels, "")`, which would not work since [replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=replace#str.replace) takes in two Strings as an argument. You need than to loop thru all vowels which is not quite efficient.

In the current state if you fixed all the SyntaxErrors you would also get an empty list, because

```
if n in vowels
```

will always return False since n is an Integer and vowels only contains Strings.

This function will do what you want:

```
def novowelsort(the_list):
    return sorted(the_list, key = lambda string : "".join([char for char in string if char not in ['a','e','i','o','u']]))
```